# Does HttpServletResponse#sendError() ever throw an IOException?

Tags: java, servlets, ioexception, http-status-codes

The [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int%29) explains that the `HttpServletResponse#sendError()` method throws an `IOException` *if an input or output exception occurs* ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) ;).

I couldn't find any scenario that makes this method throw that exception, is there any?

Comment: The underlying connection closes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What *underlying connection*? In which case does it close?

Comment: There's a socket connection that handles the HTTP connection. If a client disconnects, for whatever reason, the server won't be able to send its response. You will get an `IOException` trying to write to a disconnected `SocketOutputStream`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry, but what do you mean by *disconnects*? I.e. if he closes his browser? If yes, do you mean that if the user launches an HTTP request and closes his browser before getting the HTTP response, `sendError` will throw the `IOException`?

Comment: It could be any number of ways: closes their browser, network goes down, etc. HTTP is over TCP, which guarantees transmission. But nothing can go through a downed network or closed connection.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Interesting! Thank you, and don't hesitate to add these details in a *real* answer (only if you want +25 reputation ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTTP is sent over TCP so you can safely assume that somewhere in the underlying `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` there is a `SocketInputStream` and a `SocketOutputStream`.

If a user closes their browser or the network goes down client-side or server-side, then the server won't be able to receive requests or send responses. If the disconnection happens while the server was in the process of `sendError()`, then an IOException will occur while writing to the `SocketOutputStream`.